# Python: Checking if string follows wikipedia link format

Tags: python

If I have a string named link, how would I go about checking to see if it follows the same format as a wikipedia URL? To clarify, wikipedia URLs (in this case) always begin with en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
They can have any character (including # signs and apostrophes after the /wiki/ and spaces are indicated with underscores. Also, they can have a word in parenthesis, for example: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_Street(Elmo's_World).
For example, if the string link looked like "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_Street(Elmo's_World", that wouldn't match since there is no closing parenthesis. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this can do what you want:

```
import re
link = 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_street(Elmo\'s_world)'
sub = re.sub(r'^.{2}\.wikipedia\.org/wiki/(.*)', r'\1', link)
if sub != link:
    if '(' in sub:
        if ')' in sub:
            print 'ok'
        else:
            print 'not ok'
    else:
        print 'ok'
else:
    print 'not ok'
```

But it just checks if there is ')' sign if paranthesis was opened so if it's opened twice and closed once it will match anyway, but maybe it will help you work something out. (Btw. it will also match other languages, if only 'en' should be matched change {2} to 'en').