# Python: Check if Wikipedia Article Exists

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a Wikipedia article exists. For example,

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food
```

exists, however

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fod
```

does not, and the page simply says, "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name."

Thanks!

Comment: It's strange that it really looks like the following question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605888/python-checking-if-string-follows-wikipedia-link-format

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> print urllib.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food").getcode()
200
>>> print urllib.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fod").getcode()
404
```

is it ok?

or

```
>>> a = urllib.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fod").getcode()
>>> if a == 404:
...     print "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name."
...
Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name.
```

Comment: This is Python 2 code. In Python 3, you would use `urllib.request.urlopen` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Wikipedia Api for Python and just use the keyword to search the article.It also suggest you the closely related available articles.   Check the below example

```
>>> import wikipedia as wiki
>>> wiki.search("Barack")
    [u'Barak (given name)', u'Barack Obama', u'Barack (brandy)', u'Presidency of Barack Obama', u'Family of Barack Obama', u'First inauguration of Barack Obama', u'Barack Obama presidential campaign, 2008', u'Barack Obama, Sr.', u'Barack Obama citizenship conspiracy theories', u'Presidential transition of Barack Obama']
>>> wiki.search("Ford", results=3)
    [u'Ford Motor Company', u'Gerald Ford', u'Henry Ford']
```

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/) is the link for python module.

Answer (score 3):

Basicly, most website or web service will announce some status from each your HTTP request in the HTTP response header.
In your case, you can simply find the **status code** if is **404** while the article is not existed even though your brower rendered a page like a normol result.

```
import request
result = request.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food')
if result.status_code == 200:  # the article exists
    pass  # blablabla
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though Wikipedia does deliver a page, if you look at its request & response data, you will see:

- Status:  **Not Found**
- Code: **404**

Post Python 2.6, you can use

```
import urllib

urllib.urlopen("https://some-url").getcode()
```

to return the status code of that request to test in your code.

Comment: This is Python 2 code. In Python 3, you would use urllib.request.urlopen instead.